# Why is the stats page of rus.stackexchange.com Not Found?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

On `rus.stackexchange.com`, when I click on the "area 51" link under "more site stats on:" title on the right side bar, I am taken to [area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/rus.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/rus.stackexchange.com), but returns Page Not Found.

I think this is a bug that might need to be fixed.

Comment: You should really ask a separate question for the request of English words to be translated into Russian :) Having two unrelated issues in one question just confuses the matter, and users cannot vote one single thing, or answer you fully if they only have the answer to one of your questions (etc).

Comment: @James Sure, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That site doesn't have an Area 51 proposal since it was imported into our network rather than started from the ground up with our site launch process.

We currently only have one site setting that covers showing both stackexchange.com and Area 51 links there, and I turned it off. I'll put something in to show just stackexchange.com if there's a big need expressed by the community, but it sounds like a pretty minor loss to me.