# In Ask Patents, the link to "more site stats on Area 51" is broken

Tags: bug, broken-link, site-stats, regression, ask-patents

[Ask Patents SE](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) is a Beta site that skipped the Area 51 development phase completely, according to [Which Stack Exchange sites weren't proposed in Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284184). However, the sidebar showing the site stats still has a link to the [Area 51 proposal page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/patents.stackexchange.com) that would have existed, so naturally that link is broken.

[image: Site Stats sidebar showing the link to Area 51 under "more site stats".]

Can the link to the Area 51 proposal page of Ask Patents be removed from the site stats sidebar?

Comment: Note, it can only be removed [along with the other link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263618/152859).

Comment: Related: https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/q/355/17737 - so they broke it again...

Comment: I've brought this up on the Ask Patents Meta: https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/406/site-stats-box-is-showing-up-again

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open because Ask Patents has zero moderators and essentially zero meta-active users, so I think there's a case to make an exception to the rule that questions only about one specific site should only be posted on the per-site meta.

Comment: I'm voting to close this again because Ask Patents has since been appointed a moderator team and their meta is active again.